# Using regex to split string by Non Digit and Digit

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, split

Ive seen a few answers that are similar but none seem to go far enough.  I need to split the string when the letters change to numbers and back.  The trick is the pattern is variable meaning there can be any number of letter or number groupings.

For Example

```
AB1000 => AB 1000
ABC1500 => ABC 1500
DE160V1 => DE 160 V 1
FGG217H5IJ1 => FGG 217 H 5 IJ 1
Etc.
```

Comment: Please show us your best attempt so far, and tell us what went wrong (e.g. errors, unexpected results). Also, please explain why a regular expression is *required*. This job seems easy enough to do in a simple `for` loop (not that it would be the nicest solution, but it helps to understand the context).

Comment: The purpose for the regex is so I can put it in an extension method to be used against a linq query within a db context.  I needed to be able to group by the first 2 segments of a model name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to split the string, one way would be [lookarounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
string[] results = Regex.Split("FGG217H5IJ1", @"(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?=\d)");
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", results)); //=> "FGG 217 H 5 IJ 1"
```

Comment: I was not familar with lookarounds.  Thanks for the suggestion, it works great!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex like this:

```
[A-Z]+|\d+
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/sK4fP3/1)**